# Apache Reverse Proxy doesn't unset WWW-Authenticate Header

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, webserver, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache web server (version 2.4.52) setup as a reverse proxy.
The backend server behind the proxy issues responses with the `WWW-Authenticate`-Header set.
In the Apache proxy I want to remove this header from outgoing responses.

Trying to set the configuration option `Header always unset WWW-Authenticate` doesn't work for reasons unknown to me.
How can I make this work?
Any help is greatly appreciated.